# Identify this book in which time/magic vary locally from east to west

Tags: story-identification

I saw a review of a book two or three years ago in which time and/or magic vary from east to west. It sounded fascinating, but I sadly forgot to write down the key information. I'm pretty sure that the review was on [BoingBoing](http://boingboing.net), but their archive search is not particularly good, and I'm turning up nothing.

This one should be a lot easier than my other [stumper](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4459/2366)!

Comment: That's awfully vague, apart from the east/west detail. Magic or time? If it was time and a north/south variation, I'd say [Identify short story - war with changing time speed further from the front](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1820)

Comment: For a second I totally thought it was the Abhorsen series by Garth Nix, but I just looked it up and the variation is North-South. Bummer.

Comment: Reminds me of the moon [Ptero](http://xanth.wikia.com/wiki/Ptero) in the Xanth series, but I have no idea which book that's in.

Comment: You can do a Google search on a specific website, so for instance [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aboingboing.net+book+review+fantasy+magic+east+west) search looks through BoingBoing for something involving the terms "book review fantasy magic east west". Unfortunately all that seems to come up is the Magician King, which is a good book but not what you want :)

Comment: @Tacroy Thanks for the suggestion! I did try that -- the problem is that BoingBoing (from that time, at least) seems to be archived in per-week pages, and so keyword searches would hit across multiple items from the same week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Lifelode](http://www.librarything.com/work/7955412)* by Jo Walton has both the passage of time and the strength of magic (as well as the ease with which one can hang onto one's personal identity) varying from east to west. It was published in 2009, so it's very plausible that you would have seen a review of it two or three years ago.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a BoingBoing review for that book, but your description matches really well.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it is your story, but [Jack of Shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_Shadows) by Roger Zelazny features a world where magic and technology work on opposing sides of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Another Piers Anthony book, *Faun and Games*, the 21st Xanth novel, involves the situations of magic and technology varying from east to west on one of Ida's moons.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be [Terminal World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_World)? It isn't specifically time or magic though.

Answer (score 0):

It also vaguely sounds like the Piers Anthony "[Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_series)" series.