# Science fiction or fantasy series about people bound in life to a particular animal

Tags: story-identification, novel

Years ago I read a sci-fi/fantasy novel about people who were bound to a particular animal in life.
Started with a “Ch” I believe.

Comment: Can you go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and try to answer as many of those questions as you can? As it is, there are a lot of partial matches...

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/119322.The_Golden_Compass immediately jumps to mind for people being bound to animals, but of course the title doesn't match.

Comment: *Chrestomancei* is a popular title that fits your naming, but I don't believe there's a theme of being bound to animals.

Comment: Could you answer the following: 1) When did you read this? 2) What do you mean by being "bound"--they could speak to the animal? They could control the animal? The couldn't get too far from the animal? etc. 3) Were everyone's animals of the same species, and if not, what were some examples? 4) Were these real animals, or were they somehow magical or conjured? If magical, what could they do? 5) Was everyone bound to an animal, or just some people? And any other useful details.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4459/old-ish-fantasy-novel-about-magicians-that-have-a-characteristic-animal-form

Answer (score 4):

Possibly "The Chronicles of the Cheysuli" by Jennifer Roberson, a series of eight books beginning with "Shapechanger" (1984).

The bonding is as you describe and it starts with a Ch, so it fits the minimal clues given. See if [this link](https://www.tor.com/2016/04/06/introducing-the-cheysuli-reread/) or [this review of the first book](https://www.tor.com/2016/04/06/the-cheysuli-reread-book-1-shapechangers/) brings back memories. From the second link:

> Each Cheysuli (man) has a lir, a bonded animal who symbolises his shapechanging form—though not as an exact copy.